# Google Api not loading

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I have downloaded the Google Play Services SDK to use Google Maps in my app but when I try to import it, it doesn't find the file, even though the lib is there. Done so many times but all in vain. 
Thanks

Comment: Could you post your stack trace with the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create the correct api key. If the key is wrong the map will not load. Follow this link. It teaches maps nicely: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/